# How to count number of records in yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2

I am new in Yii framework.
I have a page frontend/site/home.php, I want to display the number of records from companies table at home.php.(DB name yii2advanced)

Comment: You need to post some code where you try to fix your problem. Atleast post your model/controller and view code

Comment: @Solmyr here's my controller code :public function actionHome()
    {
         $result = (new \yii\db\Query)
            ->select('*')
            ->from('companies')
        return $this->render('home');
        
    } and home.php code:                                                                         use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;                                                                
 <div class="col-md-2">
   <h3><?= "$result"; ?></h3>
   <h5>Companies</h5>
  </div>

Comment: @ShaileshYadav Please post your code in your question instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `count` function to get count of records from a table, like -

```
$count = YourModel::find()->count();
echo $count;
```

Comment: I get this error:- Undefined variable: count

Comment: I think it is due to you are not passing '$count' from action to view session.    
return $this->render('home',['count' => $count]);